# freemarker display ${..} as html rather than string

Tags: java, freemarker

I get html code from server to build freemarker.ftl.
Example:

Server return:
String htmlCode="<h1>Hello</h1>";

freemarker.ftl

${htmlCode}

except:

## Hello

actually: <h1>Hello</h1>

what can i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** FreeMarker 2.3.24 introduced auto-escaping, which will be on in projects that follow best practices. Typically, the default `output_format` is configured to be `HTML` (or the `ftlh` file extension is used instead of `ftl`, or the file starts with `<#ftl output_format='HTML'>`). Then the output of `${x}` will be always escaped. To prevent that, use `${x?no_esc}`. In a such configuration `#noescape` and `#escape` will give error anyway, so you will know that you have auto-escaping. See also: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_misc_autoescaping.html

**Original (outdated) answer:**

By default FreeMarker has no auto-escaping on, so it should print that value as HTML. But as it doesn't as you say, I can imagine two possibilities:

- You are inside `<#escape x as x?html>...</#escape>`, or that was added to the template by a custom `TemplateLoader`. In that case, in 2.3.x you have to write `<#noescape>${htmlCode}</#noescape>`.
- That value was escaped *before* it reaches FreeMarker. So the template already gets `&lt;h1&gt;Hello&lt;/h1&gt;` as the string.